# Sharepoint 2010 : Windows Live ACS: Redirected to Sign-In page

Tags: sharepoint-2010, acs, claims

Enviroment : SharePoint 2010

Authentication : Claims Based (Windows Live via ACS) and Windows Claims.

Authorization : User added to the Contribute group on the Site using the PUID.

Issue : Whenever the user clicks on any link on the SharePoint page, the user is redirected to the Sign-In page. This happens only for the Live users and not the Domain users.

Am I missing any configuration.